# Can I make UniCurses more Pythonic?

Tags: python, curses, unicurses

I'm a hobbyist programmer teaching myself Python. As the curses module doesn't work on Windows, I've been looking at UniCurses, a cross-platform Curses implementation. I was disappointed to find that UniCurses functions bear little resemblance to the Python style I've come to love, probably due to legacy-support and historical reasons. For instance, to add text to a "window" within the terminal, you call `waddstr(WINDOW, str, [attr])` or `mvwaddstr(WINDOW, y, x, str, [attr])`. There are dozens of these cryptically-named functions which require passing the window as a parameter, and don't treat the window as a object with methods, instance variables etc.

I would prefer to write in a more Pythonic style, where methods are called on window and panel objects e.g. `window_instance.add_string(string, [attr])`, ideally providing optional x and y parameters to the method to incorporate `mvwaddstr()` in the same method definition as `waddstr()`.

The means of implementing this that comes to mind would be defining a class for the window construct like so:

```
import unicurses 
# this would normally be 'from unicurses import * ' but I'm trying to being explicit here

...

class PseudoWindow(object):
    def __init__(self, num_cols,num_lines, begin_x, begin_y):
        self.id = unicurses.newwin(nlines, ncols, begin_y, begin_x) 
        # use this value in unicurses functions

    def __del__(self):
        unicurses.delwin(self.id)

    def add_string(self, string, [attr], x = None, y = None)
        if x is None and y is None:
            unicurses.waddstr(self.id, string, [attr])
        else:
            unicurses.mvwaddstr(self.id, string, y, x, [attr])

    # wrap further unicurses functions into methods of PseudoWindow as required
```

As an inexperienced programmer, the mental cost of switching from one vernacular to another is somewhat high, and wrapping these functions in a more familiar syntax would seem to be a big quality-of-life benefit. Am I missing something about how UniCurses is meant to be used? What are the downsides and pitfalls to wrapping the API in a further layer of abstraction in this fashion? Is there an alternative to this approach that would still allow me to use the standard object oriented Python syntax?

Comment: [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html), a built-in module, is Pythonic. `win = curses.newwin(nlines, ncols, begin_y, begin_x); win.addstr(s); win.addstr(y, x, s)`.

Comment: Your question is probably too broad, but the short answer is "go ahead and do it". There are many low-level modules which implement a traditional C-style interface which are just waiting for someone to add a proper wrapper on a more human-friendly abstraction level.